# Strange decompiled code from event subscribe code in a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-construction, delegates

This simple class

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public static void A(Window wa, Window wb)
    {
        wa.Closed += (s, e) => wb.Close();
    }
}
```

Gets compiled to this (I'm using Reflector to decompile) :

```
public class Test<T>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1
    {
        public Window wb;

        public void <A>b__0(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.wb.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void A(Window wa, Window wb)
    {
        wa.Closed += delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.wb.Close();
        };
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of `base` ? Why is `<>c__DisplayClass1` generated if it's never used ? 
Is this a Reflector bug ?

**Edit:**
Indeed, seems like Reflector optimisation isn't woking very well in this case, disabling the optimisation the decompiled code makes sense :

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public Test()
    {
        base..ctor();
        return;
    }

    public static void A(Window wa, Window wb)
    {
        <>c__DisplayClass1<T> CS$<>8__locals2;
        CS$<>8__locals2 = new <>c__DisplayClass1<T>();
        CS$<>8__locals2.wb = wb;
        wa.Closed += new EventHandler(CS$<>8__locals2.<A>b__0);
        return;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1
    {
        // Fields
        public Window wb;

        public <>c__DisplayClass1()
        {
            base..ctor();
            return;
        }

        public void <A>b__0(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.wb.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good question. I understand why you need the helper class to capture the closure over `wb`, but I don't understand the code that's actually generated in `A`, which doesn't seem to use the helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflector is "optimising" the output to try to come up with what the C# might have looked like. I don't know where the "base" bit is coming from, admittedly... but the generated class *is* definitely being used.

Set the Reflector options to "unoptimised" and you'll see something more like an IL to C# direct conversion. Or just switch to IL and read it directly, if you want a pretty raw view.