# How to detect which .NET language is calling my code

Tags: .net, reflection, cil

I'm building a library that generates a user-agent string that reports some nifty data like OS version and [currently installed .NET Framework versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed). I'm curious:

Is it possible to detect programmatically which **language** is calling my library? Or is the source language completely opaque once it's compiled into CIL?

Comment: Since an application may be assembled from pieces in several languages, what would be the benefit of knowing the language of the immediate caller?

Comment: @HABO Curiosity, mostly. I agree that the benefit is iffy since the immediate caller may not even be representative of the application at large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: I turned this into a [small library](https://github.com/nbarbettini/polyglot-dotnet) that encapsulates a few heuristics and makes it easy to call.

I came up with a heuristic that seems to work well enough for my own needs.

@Don's answer and these questions gave me some hints:

- [Decompiled DLL - Clues to help tell whether it was C# or VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184802/decompiled-dll-clues-to-help-tell-whether-it-was-c-sharp-or-vb-net)
- [Decompiling VB.Net assembly produces code with invalid member variable names; names starting with $STATIC$](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7310331/3191599)

**Caveats**:

- Only differentiates between VB.NET and C#, not any other CLR languages. Assumes C# if it doesn't have enough evidence of VB.
- It's making an educated guess, so the chance of false positives is > 0.
- Some of the hints are based on compiler implementation details, which could change.
- This seems to work on Mono too, but YMMV.
- It's expensive reflection, so in real life you'd want to wrap it in a `Lazy<>` or some other mechanism to ensure it's only called once.
- As @HABO mentioned, this may or may not be very useful information. I was mostly curious to see if it could be done.

---

```
var lang = DetectAssemblyLanguage(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());

public static string DetectAssemblyLanguage(Assembly assembly)
{
    var referencedAssemblies = assembly
        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(x => x.Name);

    var types = assembly
        .GetTypes();

    // Biggest hint: almost all VB.NET projects have a
    // hidden reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly
    bool referenceToMSVB = referencedAssemblies.Contains("Microsoft.VisualBasic");

    // VB.NET projects also typically reference the special
    // (YourProject).My.My* types that VB generates
    bool areMyTypesPresent = types.Select(x => x.FullName).Where(x => x.Contains(".My.My")).Any();

    // If a VB.NET project uses any anonymous types,
    // the compiler names them like VB$AnonymousType_0`1
    bool generatedVbNames = types.Select(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.StartsWith("VB$")).Any();

    // If a C# project uses dynamic, it'll have a reference to Microsoft.CSharp
    bool referenceToMSCS = referencedAssemblies.Contains("Microsoft.CSharp");

    // If a C# project uses any anonymous types,
    // the compiler names them like <>f__AnonymousType0`1
    bool generatedCsNames = types.Select(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.StartsWith("<>")).Any();

    var evidenceForVb = new bool[] 
    {
        referenceToMSVB,
        myTypesPresent,
        vbGeneratedNames
    };

    var evidenceForCsharp = new bool[] {
        true, // freebie. ensures ties go to C#
        referenceToMSCS,
        csGeneratedNames
    };

    var scoreForVb = evidenceForVb.Count(x => x)
                     - evidenceForCsharp.Count(x => x);

    // In the case of a tie, C# is assumed
    return scoreForVb > 0
        ? "vb"
        : "cs";
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but a C# assembly can reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (it contains a few useful types such as `TextFieldParser`), and a VB assembly could theoretically reference `Microsoft.CSharp` (much less likely IMO).

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I agree, this can produce misleading results in a lot of cases. It also doesn't work well (or at all) on .NET Core code. I'm mostly leaving this here as an interesting exercise. :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, as you have identified by mentioning the CIL.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. If however the PDB file of the corresponding .NET dll (assembly of calling code) is available, then you can inspect this file to determine the language used. However that's a big "IF" and I'd stay away from such a solution.
2. Inspect the assemblies referenced by the calling assembly. Sometimes (rarely) there could be language specific assemblies referenced.